# Accesing laptop camera with openCV

Tags: python, opencv

I run the following code, according this page - http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
print cap.read()
print cap.open()
cap.release()
```

the results I get are:

(False, None)

TypeError: Required argument 'device' (pos 1) not found

I use jupyter notebook, python 2.7, openCV 2.4.

How can I get the openCV to work with the cam?

Comment: try instead of 0 1

Comment: You are using opencv 2.4 but reading the 3.0 documentation?

Answer (score 3):

For OpenCV 2.4, use the following code:

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    
while True: 
    
    ret,img=cap.read()
    
    cv2.imshow('Video', img)
    
    if(cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('b')):
        break
```

If you still can't get the camera input, replace VideoCapture(0) with VideoCapture(1). The issue could be because of a 3rd party camera driver installed on your machine.

If that doesn't work either, try VideoCapture("path/to/saved_video"). If you have entered the file path correctly, and your OpenCV configuration has no issues, you should get saved video frames. This would imply that you need to check the camera drivers

Comment: This is very similiar to what I did, and didn't work.
I also tried `cap = cv2.VideoCapture('test.webm')` which is a video file, and it also didn't work...

Comment: What is the error with a saved file...also try an mp4

Comment: @Sarnash Kejruwal same errors as above, also in mp4.

Comment: Try putting the video in the same directory as your code and then entering just the filename in VideoCapture instead of filePath in MY code. This I'm only doing to absolutely ascertain that your openCV config has no issues. What error do you get then ?

Comment: @sarnash Kejriwal I do it from the same folder, and the error is the same as in the original question. The porblem seems to be that when i do `cap = cv2.VideoCapture('test.webm')` or `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)` the video capture does not open, and this what causes the errors... when I do `cv.isOpened()` I always get false...

Comment: What I've noticed in live cameras at times is a delay of a few frames between the camera boot and the feed initialization. Try printing the frames directly instead of checking if the camera isOpened

Answer (score 0):

use the following command to figure which device is your webcam on:

```
$ls /dev/video*
```

and use the number for `VideoCapture(num)`